How to login on Angular application using MSAL with RobotFramework Browser?
The context is end-to-end testing of an application with an Angular (15.2.9.) frontend using MSAL for authentication. The test framework used is RobotFramework.
I want to use the Browser library, based on Playwright, due to its speed and good support for shadowDOM.
I initially attempted to authenticate by setting the httpCredentials in the context:
${TEST_USR}=    Get Environment Variable    TEST_USR
${TEST_USR_PW}=    Get Environment Variable    TEST_USR_PW

${credentials}=    Create Dictionary    username=$TEST_USR    password=$TEST_USR_PW

New Persistent Context    httpCredentials=${credentials}    headless=False    url=${URL}
Reload    

This runs without errors but does not get passed SSO. If I reload the application manually on a browser, where I logged in before, I get to the main page without seeing the login popup. I expected similar behavior with the test.
First question... Why does this not work?
I took a second approach by filling in the username and passwd in the popup.
I previously was able to do this using the Selenium library with the following script:
[Setup]    Setup Test
Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
Set Window Size    ${WIDTH}    ${HEIGHT}

Click Login Button
Switch To Popup Window
Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath://*[contains(text(),'Sign in')]     timeout=20s
Sleep    1s
Capture Page Screenshot    ${SCREENSHOT_DIR}/Login_button_clicked_Screenshot.png

Set Username    id:i0116    ${TEST_USR}
Click Next Button
Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath://*[contains(text(),'Enter password')]     timeout=20s
Capture Page Screenshot    ${SCREENSHOT_DIR}/User_login_after_set_user_Screenshot.png

Set Username    id:i0118    ${TEST_USR_PW}
Click Next Button
Sleep    1s
Capture Page Screenshot    ${SCREENSHOT_DIR}/User_login_after_set_user_pw_Screenshot.png

Click Next Button
Switch To Main Window
Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath://*[contains(text(),'Project List')]
Capture Page Screenshot    ${SCREENSHOT_DIR}/User_logged_in_should_see_main_screen_Screenshot.png
Sleep    1s

Where Setup Test is getting the variables from the environment:
Setup Test
    [Documentation]    Set up the test environment.
    ${TEST_USR}=    Get Environment Variable    TEST_USR
    Set Suite Variable    ${TEST_USR}    ${TEST_USR}
    ${TEST_USR_PW}=    Get Environment Variable    TEST_USR_PW
    Set Suite Variable    ${TEST_USR_PW}    ${TEST_USR_PW}

And Switch To Popup Window is selecting the correct window:
Switch To Popup Window  
    ${handles}=    Get Window Handles
    Switch Window    ${handles}[1]  # Assuming the popup is the second window handle

I attempted to do the same with the Browser library with the following script:
    ${TEST_USR}=    Get Environment Variable    TEST_USR
    ${TEST_USR_PW}=    Get Environment Variable    TEST_USR_PW

    ${credentials}=    Create Dictionary    username=$TEST_USR    password=$TEST_USR_PW

    New Persistent Context    httpCredentials=${credentials}    headless=False    url=${URL}    
    Take Screenshot    Initial screen

    Browser.Click    text="Login"
    Take Screenshot    After Clicking Login
    Browser.Wait For Elements State    css=input[id="i0116"]    visible

This gives the following error:

[FAIL] TimeoutError: locator.waitFor: Timeout 10000ms exceeded. Call
log:

waiting for locator('input[id="i0116"]') to be visible


The login popup is displayed, but apparently, the Browser library does not detect it.
Second question... Why is this input not found? Does it need some kind of switch to a different window? If so, how to do this with the Browser library?
Thanks

httpCredentials is used only for http basic auth and i doubt MSAL uses that since its mainly deprecated. You need to implement same thing as you did for Selenium - eg, locate the popup, enter credentials and so forth..
